# NVidia, Dells, and Sleep

Tags: suspend, dell, hibernate

I recently purchased a big, heavy older Dell M6700 i7 quad core laptop as a workstation with a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.  Apart from minor things like lack of support for the Broadcom BCM5880 "Secure Application Processor)  for fingerprint and presumably bluetooth (solvable with a Plugable Bluetooth dongle), it seems fine except for the sleep feature, something I use all the time.  Putting it to sleep (hibernate?  I forget which one means flush everything to disk and power totally off to resume state later) would cause it to sleep for less than a second and instantly wake back up.

Researching this and applying the research, it turns out an underlying cause was the proprietary nVidia 390 driver.  Switching back to Nouveau driver seems to have fixed it.  It's not clear to me what the advantages are to the proprietary driver - this machine will not be used for games (well, not in the modern sense anyways), will be used for some light CAD work, mostly EE circuit boards, and some C++ application and embedded development.  We also use it for watching videos and movies.

Not having a "sleep" feature (i.e. being forced to completely shut down and having to restart all the development environments when starting up again) is a huge downside to using the proprietary nVidia driver.  What is the significant advantage, if any, to using the proprietary driver vs. Nouveau?  What are we missing out on, if anything?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

Using Nouveau solves the problem and doesn't have any obvious disadvantages compared to using the nVidia proprietary drivers.